# Add text to a PNG image on the fly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor, drawing

Not sure if this is possible, But i have a default image in my application. And when getting my data from the database, i would like to somehow append text to the image (Name), is this possible?

I have a image type - PNG
Height - 116
width - 116

this is my default img - id like to append the name to it (determined by the DB)

[image]

And i would like to append something like this to it at run time

[image]

Heres my code (Not sure if its applicable, but im just calling the picture from root)

```
<div class="card-block" id="appSearch">
                                        <div class="row" id="NONdraggablePanelList">

                                            @foreach (var app in Applications)
                                            {
                                                <div data-target="#requestAccessForm" id="@app.Id" @onclick="@(e => GetAppRolesDetails(app.Id))" data-toggle="modal" style="cursor: pointer" class="col-lg-12 col-xl-2" data-role="apps">
                                                    <div class="card-sub" style="text-align: center">
                                                        <span class="btn tts tts-slideOut" aria-label=@app.Description>
                                                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="./_content/Skclusive.Dashboard.App.View/images/AppImg/Default3.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                                        </span>
                                                        <a href="https://hey.co.uk:44301/IADJ">
                                                            <div class="card-block">
                                                                <h5 hidden="hidden" class="card-title">@app.Name</h5>
                                                                <b>@app.Name</b>
                                                                <br/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Just on screen or also when the images is downloaded?

Comment: Set the image as background of a `div`,and add text to the `div`?